# Como implementar a classe Parcelable?

Tags: android, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Necessito de ajuda na questão de orientação a objetos.

Preciso implementar a classe `Parcelable` no model `Produto`, mas por questão de organização, não gostaria de implementar diretamente na classe `Produto` e sim criar uma nova classe `ProdutoParcelable` e implementar ali e fazer com que a classe `Produto` identifique essa implementação ou "se torne" essa implementação.

O detalhe é que na possível classe `ProdutoParcelable` vou precisar dos atributos da classe `Produto`.

```
public class Produto extends ProdutoParcelable

public class ProdutoParcelable implements Parcelable
//Aqui vou precisar dos atributos de Produto
```

Comment: Se nessa classe você precisará dos atributos da classe filha, sua abstração do problema está errada. Qual seria o objetivo de dividir em classes diferentes?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O objetivo seria simplesmente organização. Deixar a classe Produto mais limpa. Obrigado.

Comment: Então por quê não define os atributos de `Produto` que serão necessários em `ProdutoParcelable` diretamente nesta classe?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Vou tentar! Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1):

No caso do seu problema, eu usaria uma interface Produto, onde ela iria listar os atributos de um produto, e criaria uma classe `ProdutoModel` e `ProdutoParcelable`, ambas implementando Produto. Assim, quando você fosse criar um produto normal (sem Parcelable) tu usaria `Produto produto = new ProdutoModel();`. Mas eu não indico você fazer duas classes para isso, você está aumentando a complexidade de entendimento do seu código sem necessidade e pode ser que num futuro você se enrole com isso. Experiência própria.

Sobre a implementação do Parcelable, acesse [esse link](http://cafecomandroid.com.br/2016/09/20/por-que-usar-o-parcelable-ao-inves-do-serializable/) que tem um tutorial completo lá.

Comment: Às vezes é adequado fazer um DTO de serialização distinto do objeto de negócio, daí a necessidade do Rafa Yaw. Também é interessante tentar focar no negócio o negócio, e na serialização a serialização. Misturar as duas responsabilidades pode (mas não necessariamente) deixar o código... sujo?, poluído?, feio?, contra intuitivo? Como sempre, depende do caso

Comment: Isso, eu passei por uma situação dessa e tive certos problemas, mas eu entendo a premissa do Rafa, enfim, Contando que esteja bem documentado não vai haver problemas.